# Cannot store data in the arrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

Thanks for all the help guys, but now the nature of the question has changed based on Patrick's suggestion below. The loop is running but it does not seem to be storing the input to respective arrays. Data keeps getting replaced into the Array-Lists rather than going to the next position into the Array-List any suggestions?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrray {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<String> names;
        ArrayList<String> addr;

        do {
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
            addr = new ArrayList<String>();
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Name and Adreess are: " + names.size() + "**"
                    + addr.size());
            System.out.println("please Enter Your Name :");
            names.add(userInput.next());
            System.out.println("please enter your Address  :");
            addr.add(userInput.next());

            System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)" );
            String ans =userInput.next();  // get the value from the user using scanner class
            if(ans.equals("n") || ans.equals("N"))
                break;

           } while (true);
        int n = names.size();
        int a = addr.size();
        for(int i =0; i<n && i<a; i++ )
            System.out.println("Name and address are as below:  "+ names.get(i)+"**"+ addr.get(i));

    }
}
```

Comment: Who is Patrick? We can't see anything before you edited, so we're not sure what's going on. Did you create a new question instead of editing a previous one? You should add a tag specifying the language you're using.

Comment: Can you please use punctuation to identify the start and end of your sentences?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is re-initializing the `ArrayList` everytime it runs. You need to take it out of the loop.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrray {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> addr = new ArrayList<String>();

        do {
            //names = new ArrayList<String>(); take this out
            //addr = new ArrayList<String>();  // take this out
            Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Name and Adreess are: " + names.size() + "**"
                    + addr.size());
            System.out.println("please Enter Your Name :");
            names.add(userInput.next());
            System.out.println("please enter your Address  :");
            addr.add(userInput.next());

            System.out.println("Do you want to add another entry? :(y/n)" );
            String ans =userInput.next();  // get the value from the user using scanner class
            if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                break;

           } while (true);
        int n = names.size();
        int a = addr.size();
        for(int i =0; i<n && i<a; i++ )
            System.out.println("Name and address are as below:  "+ names.get(i)+"**"+ addr.get(i));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new ArrayList every time you go through the loop. That means that the final array will only contain the last element.
Create them before the loop instead.